# if i type in text box the marker will take the value for long,latitude. but not triggering when it enters the polygon

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When I drag and drop marker on polygon it gives the alert `google.maps.event.addListener(marker0, '**dragend**', function(e)`, if I disable drag marker.

How can I determine whether the entered values are inside of or outside of a polygon?

```js
function initialize() {
    x = document.getElementById("x").value;
    y = document.getElementById("y").value;
    var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(14.466465, -56.118292);
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(x, y);
    var mapProp = {
        center: latLng,
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

    var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myCenter,
        title: 'Point A',
        draggable: true,
    });

    marker1.setMap(map);

    var marker0 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        title: 'BWE',
        map: map,
        draggable: true,

    });
    marker0.setMap(map);

    var myCity = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: latLng,
        radius: 100,
        strokeColor: "#0000FF",
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: "#0000FF",
        fillOpacity: 0.4
    });
    myCity.setMap(map);


    var ne0 = new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262);
    var ne01 = new google.maps.LatLng(18.466465, -66.118292);
    var ne02 = new google.maps.LatLng(32.321384, -64.75737);

    var n0 = new google.maps.LatLng(14.466465, -56.118292);
    var n01 = new google.maps.LatLng(27.774252, -30.190262);
    var n02 = new google.maps.LatLng(22.321384, -54.75737);
    var n03 = new google.maps.LatLng(32.321384, -60.75737);

    var zone = [
    n0, n01, n02, n03];
    var zone0 = [
    ne0, ne01, ne02, ne0];

    var dzone = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: zone,
        strokeColor: "#0000FF",
        strokeOpacity: 1.5,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: "#ff0000",
        fillOpacity: 1,
        clickable: false
    });
    dzone.setMap(map);

    var dzone0 = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: zone0,
        strokeColor: "#0000FF",
        strokeOpacity: 1.5,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: "#ff0000",
        fillOpacity: 1,
        clickable: false
    });
    dzone0.setMap(map);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker0, 'dragend', function (e) {
        if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(e.latLng, dzone)) {
            window.open("siren.html", "mywindow");

            window.alert("Danger!");;
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        } else if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(e.latLng, dzone0)) {
            window.open("siren.html", "mywindow");

            window.alert("Danger!");;
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        } else {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        }
        var m = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: e.latLng,
            map: map,
            icon: 'pi.png'
        })
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>Langtitude
<input id="x" type="number" value="14" onkeyup="initialize('x')">Altitude
<input id="y" type="number" value="-56" onkeyup="initialize('y')">
<button type="button" onclick="initialize()">Submit</button>&nbsp;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're using the [geometry](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry) library with lines like `google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(e.latLng, dzone)`

However you've not loaded the geometry library in.  Change:

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

to:

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry"></script>
```

Comment: thank you, but one more doubt pls refer the below link    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29843155/if-i-enter-value-in-text-box-equalent-to-polygon-value-im-not-getting-alert-msg