# if i enter value in text box equalent to polygon value i'm not getting alert msg

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

If I drag marker release on polygon I got an alert but if I enter long, latitude values through text box, marker moves but no alert msg ,(marker0, 'dragend', function(e) instead of dragend is there any event to grap values from text box, pls guide me

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry"></script>
<script>
function initialize()
{
  x = document.getElementById("x").value ;
  y = document.getElementById("y").value ;
  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(x, y);
var mapProp = {
  center:latLng,
  zoom:15,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
var marker1=new google.maps.Marker({
  position:latLng,title: 'Point A',
  draggable: true,
  });
marker1.setMap(map);
var ne0=new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262);
var ne01=new google.maps.LatLng(18.466465, -66.118292);
var ne02=new google.maps.LatLng(32.321384, -64.75737);

var n0=new google.maps.LatLng(23.774252, -78.190262);
var n01=new google.maps.LatLng(17.466465, -65.118292);
var n02=new google.maps.LatLng(16.466465, -63.118292);
var n03=new google.maps.LatLng(30.321384, -64.75737);     
var zone = [
    n0,n01,n02,n03
  ];
 var zone0 = [
    ne0,ne01,ne02,ne0
  ];
  var dzone = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: zone,
strokeColor:"#0000FF",
  strokeOpacity:1.5,
  strokeWeight:2,
  fillColor:"#ff0000",
  fillOpacity:1,clickable: false 
  });dzone.setMap(map);
  
var dzone0 = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: zone0,
strokeColor:"#0000FF",
  strokeOpacity:1.5,
  strokeWeight:2,
  fillColor:"#ff0000",
  fillOpacity:1,clickable: false 
  });dzone0.setMap(map);

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'dragend', function(e){
    var result;
    if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(e.latLng, dzone)) {
    
 window.alert("Danger!");;
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    } 
 else if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(e.latLng, dzone0)) {
      
 window.alert("Danger!");;
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    } else {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }

   var m = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: e.latLng,
      map: map,
     icon:'pi.png'
    })
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
Langtitude <input id="x" type="number" value = "25.774252" onkeyup="initialize('x')">

latitude <input id="y" type="number"value = "-80.190262" onkeyup="initialize('y')"><br> <br>
<button type="button" onclick="initialize()">Submit</button> &nbsp;

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trigger the dragend event when you use the form to move the marker.

```
google.maps.event.trigger(marker1,'dragend',{latLng:marker1.getPosition()});
```

code snippet:

```js
function initialize()
{
x = document.getElementById("x").value ;
y = document.getElementById("y").value ;

  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(x, y);

var mapProp = {
  center:latLng,
  zoom:15,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

var marker1=new google.maps.Marker({
  position:latLng,title: 'Point A',

 draggable: true,

  });

marker1.setMap(map);

var ne0=new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262);
var ne01=new google.maps.LatLng(18.466465, -66.118292);
var ne02=new google.maps.LatLng(32.321384, -64.75737);

var n0=new google.maps.LatLng(23.774252, -78.190262);
var n01=new google.maps.LatLng(17.466465, -65.118292);
var n02=new google.maps.LatLng(16.466465, -63.118292);
var n03=new google.maps.LatLng(30.321384, -64.75737);
 
var zone = [
    n0,n01,n02,n03
  ];
 var zone0 = [
    ne0,ne01,ne02,ne0
  ];

  var dzone = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: zone,
strokeColor:"#0000FF",
  strokeOpacity:1.5,
  strokeWeight:2,
  fillColor:"#ff0000",
  fillOpacity:1,clickable: false 
  });dzone.setMap(map);
  
var dzone0 = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: zone0,
strokeColor:"#0000FF",
  strokeOpacity:1.5,
  strokeWeight:2,
  fillColor:"#ff0000",
  fillOpacity:1,clickable: false 
  });dzone0.setMap(map);

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'dragend', function(e){
    var result;
    if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(e.latLng, dzone)) {
    
 window.alert("Danger!");;
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    } 
 else if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(e.latLng, dzone0)) {
      
 window.alert("Danger!");;
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    } else {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }

   var m = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: e.latLng,
      map: map,
     icon:'pi.png'
    })
  });
  google.maps.event.trigger(marker1,'dragend',{latLng:marker1.getPosition()});
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry"></script>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
Langtitude <input id="x" type="number" value = "25.774252" onkeyup="initialize('x')" />

latitude <input id="y" type="number"value = "-80.190262" onkeyup="initialize('y')" /><br> <br>
<button type="button" onclick="initialize()">Submit</button> &nbsp;

  </div>
```

Comment: thank you..one more doubt when i type new lang, longitutde in textbox map reloads instead of moving to new location.is there any option to stop reloading of map and only update marker position  @geocodezip

Comment: That is the way you wrote the code (it calls initialize whenever the marker/position changes).  If you don't want it to do that, change your code. `onkeyup="initialize('x')"`

Comment: I plan to Get data from gps device to server ,, from server using php push the data to website text box to update long,latitude for marker..wht changes are needed to stop the updating of map alone...pls guide me...@geocodezip